# Why are my 'min' and 'max' form functions not working?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, max, min

I made a custom form to display in Wordpress Woocommerce checkout page, where user must select their age before making the purchase.

The idea is so that people who are under 18 years old would not be able to make a purchase.

Currently, the code displays the form and it is all set, but 'min' and 'max' features, which I would require to limit age insertion between 18 and 99, do not apply for some reason.
What do I require in order to make 'min' and 'max' functions to apply?

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Vanusepiirang') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_name', array(
        'type'      => 'number',
        'id'        => 'vanusepiirang',
        'name'      => 'vanusepiirang',
        'min'       =>  18,
        'max'       =>  99,
        'required'  =>  1,
        'class'     => array(
            'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ),
        'label'     => __('Sisestage enda vanus. Teie sünnipäeva küsime kinnituseks, et olete piisavalt vana ostukorvis olevate toodete ostmiseks.') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Teie vanus') ,
    ),

    $checkout->get_value('custom_field_name'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I expect 'min' and 'max' features to apply on the form, so that numbers 1-17 cannot be passed through.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [woocommerce_form_field](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/6540e894251e95d77c452a2f00f57561cdcd69b3/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2540) function definition, `max` and `min` attributes must be passed as custom_attribute. Your final code must be modified as below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Vanusepiirang') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_name', array(
        'type'      => 'number',
        'id'        => 'vanusepiirang',
        'name'      => 'vanusepiirang',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'min'       =>  18,
            'max'       =>  99,
        ),
        'required'  =>  1,
        'class'     => array(
            'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ),
        'label'     => __('Sisestage enda vanus. Teie sünnipäeva küsime kinnituseks, et olete piisavalt vana ostukorvis olevate toodete ostmiseks.') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Teie vanus') ,
    ),

    $checkout->get_value('custom_field_name'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Also you should consider that, first argument of the `woocommerce_form_field` function is the field name and ID, unless you pass an ID parameter separately in the second argument. Which means, because of the `'name' => 'vanusepiirang'` key-value generated input html will contain two different name attribute. I recommend to remove `'name' => 'vanusepiirang'` part from your source code.

Comment: Thank you for the code and feedback on the 'name' field. I tried the updated code - It works the same way, as the original one. I've included an image of the situation: https://imgur.com/ClFcPlq . The 'else if' functions i've wrote earlier sort of solve the issue, but i'd rather have the selector be 18-99 to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of helped myself out with a different kind of solution :)

Added this to my 'empty field check function':

```
else if ($_POST['custom_field_name'] < ('18'))
    wc_add_notice(__('Te pole piisavalt vana nende toodete ostmiseks!') , 'error');
else if ($_POST['custom_field_name'] > ('99'))
    wc_add_notice(__('Palun sisesta korrektne vanus!') , 'error');
```